# How do I encode my password for Equinix authentication API using md5-b64?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to call the Equinix authentication API after encoding my password but the hashing isn’t successful.

I tried the following online generators but the encoded password appears to be incorrect.

https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/md5.html

https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and used Jython to solve the issue. 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjythonstandalone252jar.htm

The code is quite straight forward:

```
import hashlib
import base64

password = "my_password"
hashObject = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
md5password = hashObject.digest()
base64Password = base64.b64encode(md5password)
```

encode() function - encodes the password to a byte string which is used as input to the hashlib.md5() method

digest() function - returns the encoded data in byte format
and b64encode() encodes the data returned by the digest () method

You can also test this out here
https://repl.it/repls/JampackedShowyLocatorprogram

Hope this helps :)